# Cross-referencing of citations does not work in Tufte-Book format

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am new to this forum and would like thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I downloaded the standard Tufte-Book template from Overleaf. I'm using it to write a book. I'm very happy with the results, but am encountering a problem with the cross-referencing of citations.

The `\cite` command works fine; the cited reference appears in the margin, as expected.

When I type `\cite{}` and begin to enter text within the brackets, a list appears of the items that are. available for citation in my bibliography appears (as expected).

The problem arises when I try to cross-reference something I have already cited previously. Use of:

`\cref{example-reference}` does not work; nor does use of
`\citeref{example-reference}` or
`\ref{example-reference}`

In each of these three cases (`\cref{}`, `\citeref{}`, and `\ref{}`) when I begin typing in the brackets I do not see a list of the references in the bibliography - as there was with use of `\cite{}`. I get "??" on output and the warning that "example-reference" is undefined.

I am able to use `\cref{}` successfully for cross-referencing chapters and figures - it is only references that appear to be problematic.

Any ideas how I might resolve this problem?

---

I want to use `\cite{example-reference1}` only once. If I use `\cite{example-reference1}` on multiple occasions, then the citation number is incremented and the citation text is repeated.

Let's say that `\cite{example-reference1}` is my first citation, and yields this result:

1{text-for-example-reference1}

where the "1" is a superscript before the text of the citation itself.

Later in the same chapter, I'd like to reference the already-cited material without incrementing "1" to "2" and without repeating the citation text. I'd like the result of `\ref{example-reference1}` to be "[1]" or "1". This seems like it must be a very common situation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Isn't `\cite` good enough to create citation call-outs? Why do you need to combine it with a cross-referencing command?

Comment: Your question is hard to understad with no example. `\cite` is used to refer to entries in the bibliography and `\ref` is used to refer to sections or figures in the current document. You seem to be using the same arguments for both, which seems very unusual.

Comment: Do you want to have a "Supra, note X"-type output on second and subsequent cites of a work? The ibidtracker=true, citetracker=true options for biblatex help do that, for example. But the answer depends on the actual code and settings you use, so a compilable example/test document showing the issue is going to be needed to tailor a solution for your case.